# Fill the html ,,name" divs from array of objects using for and forEach loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, dataset, fill

I have been wrapping my head around this one for quite a time now.
I would like to fill up h2 elements with name class in html from js array of objects. I tried for and forEach loops but all i've got is filling the html elements (success) but with only one single name from the array (the very last one).

I see that i can do this with maybe dataset (data-id) property, but I am curious if i can do this all with just loops.

Thanks for help.

Here is my code:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
      <section>
        <div class="notification">
          <h2 class="name" id="firstName"></h2>
          <p class="notif-text">reacted to your recent post My first tournament today!</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="notification">
          <h2 class="name" id="secondName"></h2>
          <p class="notif-text">followed you</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="notification">
          <h2 class="name"></h2>
          <p class="notif-text">has joined your group Chess Club</p>
        </div>
      </section>
</div>
```

```
const people = [

{fullName: 'Mark Webber', notifText: 'reacted to your recent post My first tournament today!', time: '1m ago', message: ''},

    {fullName: 'Angela Grey', notifText: 'followed you', time: '5m ago', message: ''},
    {fullName: 'Jacob Thompson', notifText: 'has joined your group Chess Club', time: '1 day ago', message: ''},

    {fullName: 'Rizky Hasanuddin', notifText: 'sent you a private message', time: '5 days ago', message: `Hello, thanks for setting up the Chess Club. I have been a member for a few weeks now and
    I am already having lots of fun and improving my game.`},
    {fullName: 'Kimberly Smith', notifText: 'commented on your picture', time: '1 week ago', message: ''},

    {fullName: 'Nathan Peterson', notifText: 'reacted to your recent post 5 end-game strategies to increase your win rate', time: '2 weeks ago', message: ''},

    {fullName: 'Anna Kim', notifText: 'left the group Chess Club', time: '2 weeks ago', message: ''}
]


 let names = document.querySelectorAll('.name')


 for(let i = 0; i < people.length; i++ ) {  

    names.forEach(function(oneName){
        oneName.textContent = people[i].fullName
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow for injecting HTML Components inside your `all_asset` div, using a defined list of objects is pretty simple:

1. Get div element.
2. Create a list of divs using a array of objects.
3. Use a forEach loop to insert our div objects into our main div element.

Below is a example on how to achieve this:

```
    // The original object given by you
    const givenAssets = {
      1: ['Boat', 0, '10000'],
      2: ['Carriage', 2, '30000']
    };
    
    // Get DOM Element with ID #all_asset
    const assetContainer = document.querySelector('#all_asset');
    
    // Define a class that will represent each object
    class Asset {
      // Set parameters
      constructor(id, name, price, age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.age = age;
      }
    
      // Create HTML with your objects, using the array and Asset class
      addHtml() {
        // Variable HTML: Elements as string.
        let html = `
          <div class="touch_box col-sm-12" id="list_asset${this.id}">
            <br>
            <h4 id="asset_name${this.id}">${this.name}</h4>
            <p id="asset_price${this.id}">${this.price}</p>
            <hr>
            <p id="asset_age${this.id}">${this.age}</p>
            <hr>
          </div>`;
          
        // Add your objects inside #all_asset div using beforeend method
        assetContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
      }
    }
    
    // List of your Assets
    let assets = [];

    // For each object in your array, push them into our assets list
    for (const key in givenAssets) {
      assets.push(new Asset(key, givenAssets[key][0], givenAssets[key][1], givenAssets[key][2]))
    }
    
    // For each asset in assets[], addHtml() will add them inside #all_asset
    assets.forEach(asset => asset.addHtml());
```

Index.html:

```
<div id="all_asset">
  <!-- The assets.forEach loop will add your objects inside this div. -->
</div>
```

Recommended Documentation reading, for clearer comprehension:

- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#examples)
- [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#examples)
- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#examples)

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solution and it also worked. I was making mistake choosing all names with querySelector() instead of whole container... and then returned it in new html

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container')


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const showInHTML = people.map((person, index) => {
        return `<section>
        <div class="notification">
          <h2 class="name" id="firstName">${person.fullName}</h2>
          <p class="notif-text">reacted to your recent post My first tournament today!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <p class="time-date">1m ago</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <p class="message-text"></p>
        </div>
      </section>`
    }).join('')

    container.innerHTML = showInHTML
})
```